# how to upload zip/rar files in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

how to upload zip/rar files in codeigniter
itried like this

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'application/x-zip|application/x-zip-compressed|application/octet-stream|application/x-compress|application/x-compressed|multipart/x-zip';
```

but not working . please help me.................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$config['allowed_types'] is a list of permitted *extensions* rather than mimetypes. Instead you would use:

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'zip|rar';
```

Check the CodeIgniter user guide on [File Uploading](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, your problem is that you want to upload a non-image file type.
Theres a bug in codeigniter's upload library, around the 566th line.

`// Images get some additional checks
            if (in_array($val, $image_types))
            {
                if (getimagesize($this->file_temp) === FALSE)
                {
                    return FALSE;
                }
            }`

I've commented it out, so i can upload non-image files as well.

I really hope this helps ;)